# React Native Elements ListItem.Accordion items cause SectionList to scroll (much) further than desired

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm using a react-native-elements `ListItem.Accordion` because everything else in my React Native `SectionList` uses `ListItem`s (and the documentation seems un-opinionated about this), and I'm very happy with the rendering. Unfortunately, when scrolling down it scrolls beyond the last displayed item until it gets to where the end ***would*** be ***if*** all the accordion items were fully expanded.

Obviously, when all the accordion items are expanded it stops scrolling when it gets to the end.

How do I get the `SectionList` to only scroll to what's visible when the accordion items are not expanded?

```
    const renderSectionHeader = ({ section: { title, data } }) => {
        return { data.length > 0 ? (
            <Text>{title}</Text>
        ) : null };
    }

    const renderSeparator = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{
                height: 1,
                backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
                marginLeft: "5%",
                width: "90%",
            }} />
        );
    };

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <ListItem.Accordion
                content={
                    <>
                        <MaterialIcons.Button
                            name="shopping-basket"
                            style={{paddingLeft:20}}
                            onPress={() => { alert(item.greeting) }} />
                        <ListItem.Content style={{marginLeft:15}}>
                            <ListItem.Title>{item.title}</ListItem.Title>
                            <ListItem.Subtitle>{item.subtitle}</ListItem.Subtitle>
                        </ListItem.Content>
                    </>
                }
                isExpanded={isExpanded}
                onPress={() => {
                    toggleAccordionItem(item.key);
                }}
            >
                <ListItem item={item}>
                    <MaterialIcons.Button
                        name="airport-shuttle"
                        onPress={() => { alert(item.direction) }}>
                        <Text>Show Direction</Text>
                    </MaterialIcons.Button>
                </ListItem>
            </ListItem.Accordion>
        );
    };

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <SectionList
                refreshing={!isRefreshing}
                sections={sections}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Try providing a ListFooterComponent prop to your SectionList, and put a React Fragment there.

Comment: In my actual code I have a `ListFooterComponent` that renders nothing if there are items and a `Text` element that says "Loading..." if there aren't. No difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Don’t pass it a ternary, just the Fragment bc when your ListItems are unmounted the SectionList may re-render based on the content there. I’m not sure what the business logic is but I think there’s a chance my previous suggestion works.

Comment: Could you tell us how you manage the `toggleAccordionItem(item.key);` to expand the selected one?

Comment: And also, did you finally get any solution to the problem?

Comment: @EstebanChornet : see https://gist.github.com/therightstuff/c691970b88c013e41dc5f757594ce305 for the toggleAccordionItem implementation. unfortunately, i haven't yet found a solution :(

Comment: FYI, another approach you can make is to have another state `selectedItemIndex`, and in the `onPress`, you set the `selectedItemIndex` then the `isExpanded` and you check in the `isExpanded` property wheter` isExpanded && selectedItemIndex === index`.

Concerning the scroll, I think is not well implemented in RN elements... For the moment, I've decided to switch to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible. It works well on web, android & iOS (at least for what I wanted to accomplish).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just started using React Native last week, but my workaround for a similar situation was to use the ListItem inside the accordion like this

```
{isExpanded && <ListItem item={item} />}
```

But it turns the animation of the accordion clunky. Don't know which is the correct way to address the issue, if someone has experiencied this issue before and know what is the proper way to solve i would appreciate

Comment: It looks like this is the way to do it! It feels like a hack, but the performance is good for me, thank you.